# Rails: Private journal entries for a Journal supporting many Users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js

I'd like to build a Backbone/Rails Journal App that supports many Users.

How would you persist a journal Entry for a given User, while respecting that User's privacy (the User can store sensitive info in that Entry)? I was thinking of using something like BCrypt, but that wouldn't work since you can't invert the process. Any thoughts?

In this case, I'm trying to keep the app as lightweight as possible, so answers that don't rely on external libraries would be preferred (not sure if that's an unreasonable requirement though).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you trust the server to send you encryption code, you trust it with the way it handles your data. That's mostly the issue with client-side encryption.

If the user doesn't know how to use their own encryption tools, then they're trusting you with the tools you send them.

That said, if you're still pretty gung-ho about it, maybe consider a web-based version of PGP: https://webpg.org/

Comment: This is reasonable, gives and extra reference, and similar answers have been given to me outside of SO. Therefore I'm marking this question as answered.